# How to select both single and multiple date in MultiDatePicker in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, multidatepicker

I am new in SwiftUI and I am facing problem with selecting Single date with MultiDatePicker

my code is like this

```
    @State private var dateRange: ClosedRange<Date>? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
    MultiDatePicker(dateRange: self.$dateRange)
    
     Button(action: {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
          getDateRangeGuest(dateRange: dateRange)
         }
     }, label: {
         Text("OK")
           .font(.title3)
      })
    }
    
    func getDateRangeGuest(dateRange: ClosedRange<Date>?){
       if let range = dateRange {
          var newRange = String()
          newRange = "\(range)"
          print(newRange)
       }else{
        print(dateRange)
     }
}
```

Is it is possible to select also a Single date in MultiDatePicker?

I want it in `range` not in `Set<DateComponents> array`

[image]

Comment: So you want to select both single date [ Eg: 15/06/2023] and Multiple dates with range [ 12/06/2023...<15/06/2023] ?

Comment: @KushBhavsar Single date eg: 15/06/2023 and 12/06/2023...15/06/2023 in range

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use WWCalendarTimeSelector calender. As it is in Swift I finally created its SwiftUI Version

```
    import SwiftUI
    import WWCalendarTimeSelector
    
    class CalendarSelectorDelegate: WWCalendarTimeSelectorProtocol {
        @Binding var singleDate: Date?
        @Binding var selectedDateString: String
        @Binding var multipleDates: [Date]
        @Binding var startDateGlobal: String
        @Binding var endDateGlobal: String
        
        init(singleDate: Binding<Date?>, selectedDateString: Binding<String>, multipleDates: Binding<[Date]>, startDateGlobal: Binding<String>, endDateGlobal: Binding<String>) {
            _singleDate = singleDate
            _selectedDateString = selectedDateString
            _multipleDates = multipleDates
            _startDateGlobal = startDateGlobal
            _endDateGlobal = endDateGlobal
        }
        
        func WWCalendarTimeSelectorDone(_ selector: WWCalendarTimeSelector, date: Date) {
            print("Selected \n\(date)\n---")
            singleDate = date
            selectedDateString = date.stringFromFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        }
        
        func WWCalendarTimeSelectorDone(_ selector: WWCalendarTimeSelector, dates: [Date]) {
            print("Selected Multiple Dates \n\(dates)\n---")
            
            var startDateSend = String()
            var endDateSend = String()
            
            if let date = dates.first {
                singleDate = date
                let firstDate = date.stringFromFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                let newDate = dates.last
                let lastDate = newDate!.stringFromFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                selectedDateString = "\(firstDate) - \(lastDate)"
                startDateSend = date.stringFromFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                endDateSend = newDate!.stringFromFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
            } else {
                selectedDateString = "No Date Selected"
            }
            
            print("Label Value = ", selectedDateString)
            multipleDates = dates
            startDateGlobal = startDateSend
            endDateGlobal = endDateSend
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var singleDate: Date?
        @State private var selectedDateString = ""
        @State private var multipleDates: [Date] = []
        @State private var startDateGlobal = ""
        @State private var endDateGlobal = ""
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text(selectedDateString)
                    .padding()
                
                Button(action: {
                    showCalendar()
                }) {
                    Text("Select Date")
                }
            }
        }
        
        func showCalendar() {
            let selector = WWCalendarTimeSelector.instantiate()
selector.optionSelectionType = WWCalendarTimeSelectorSelection.range
            let delegate = CalendarSelectorDelegate(singleDate: $singleDate, selectedDateString: $selectedDateString, multipleDates: $multipleDates, startDateGlobal: $startDateGlobal, endDateGlobal: $endDateGlobal)
            selector.delegate = delegate
            
            if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
                scene.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(selector, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

MultiDatePicker is used to select multiple dates. Here the range between which dates are being selected can be modified. If you have to select single date then there are other ways provided by apple.

One of the way I can think of is by providing range on single date, but I don't think that's what you need.
There could be a solution to show multi-picker and single-picker within if.. else.. clause.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/multidatepicker

`MultiDatePicker(titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, selection: Binding<Set<DateComponents>>, in: Range<Date>)`

Comment: If using <Set<DateComponents>> it is selection different date not a range

Comment: Sorry for late response. I am not aware if any range picker is available in iOS. As far as i know multiple date selection and single date selection both are possible and we can restrict selection between certain range as well.

Comment: For range selection you can create custom component though

Comment: How can I create custom component?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample code showcasing how you can utilise a `MultiDatePicker` to choose both individual and multiple dates:

```
struct MultiDatePickerDemo: View {
    @State private var selectedDates: Set<DateComponents> = []
    @State private var formattedDates: String = ""
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MultiDatePicker("Single/Multiple Date Picker", selection: $selectedDates)

            Button(action: {
                formatSelectedDates()
            }, label: {
                Text("OK")
                    .font(.title3)
            })
        }
    }
    
    private func formatSelectedDates() {
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-YY"
        let selectedDates = selectedDates
            .compactMap { date in
                Calendar.current.date(from: date)
            }
            .compactMap { date in
                formatter.string(from: date)
            }
        
        print(selectedDates)
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to select ClosedRange<Date>? not Set<DateComponents>. Set<DateComponents> does not select range it select date separately.

Comment: Need to select one from this  enum PickerType {
        case singleDay
        case anyDays
        case dateRange
    }
    in MultiDatePicker.